# Not able to make Magnific and Masonry work together

Tags: jquery

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn283/VC9dz/4/)

So I'm working on my portfolio site and I want to use Masonry to layout my work images and Magnific for my lightbox. The trouble I'm running into is I can only get one or the other to work. I'm 90% sure it's some really easy naming/syntax error I'm making, but I don't know enough about programming to solve it on my own.

The above link has Masonry working but no Magnific....any help would be appreciated.

**jQ**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     function masonry() {
         //masonry
         var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
         var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
             itemSelector: '.item',
             columnWidth: '.item',
             isFitWidth: true
         });
     };

     masonry();

     $('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
         delegate: 'a',
         type: ' image',
         closeOnContentClick: true,
         showCloseBtn: true,
     });
 });

 $('.child').each(function () {
     $(this).magnificPopup({
         delegate: '.image-link',
         type: 'image',
         gallery: {
             enabled: true
         }
     });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
            <img src="images//preggers_240.jpg" width="240" height="165">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/PRObroch_240.jpg" width="240" height="180">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/SA_Ad1_240.jpg" width="240" height="298">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/asskick_240.jpg" width="240" height="160">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/yowie_240.jpg" width="240" height="310">
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/202A0389_240.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/202A8355_240.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/202A9385_240.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/8583068635_8abc5248d1_o_240.jpg" width="240" height="360" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/derm_PC_240.jpg" width="240" height="180" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/FDFC_BCS_240.jpg" width="240" height="240" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/home_240.png" width="240" height="230" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/IMG_1883_240.jpg" width="240" height="160" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/NB_banners_240.jpg" width="240" height="360" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/promo_july_240.jpg" width="240" height="297" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/promo_freight_240.jpg" width="240" height="125" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/SA-2828_240.jpg" width="240" height="386" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/SA_Ad1_240.jpg" width="240" height="298" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="/images/skills_home_240.jpg" width="240" height="240" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="/images/summer_savings_240.jpg" width="240" height="243" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/usb_key_case_240.jpg" width="240" height="161" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: fiddle is not at all working...you haven't added `jquery` lib file in it plus images are missing from it too...update fiddle and u'll have an answer for sure!! :D

Comment: Thanks for that, first time using jsfiddle *surprise!*

Comment: i realized that after posting my comment, apologies for that...Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my problem...

By adding another div class to separate my popup-gallery and my masonry items, both of them are working correctly together.